# Front Page of Site Has Gone Replaced By Random Page

Tags: plugins

After I installed WP-Cerber plugin, did some settings like IP Match, custom URL for login etc, and then i logged out from wordpress, then next day, i logged in, the front page of the site was gone. It is replaced by a random unknown page of the site. All other pages are working well except the front page.

I have tried deleting the plugin. I also tried installing WP-Cerber-Reset. Reinstalled WP Cerber. Put settings to Default. But nothing has changed. Need ideas please.

Comment: Did you check your homepage settings in the admin > settings > reading?

Comment: Yea, "Home" is set there. Besides, I have also tried to change it to blog, about etc. Nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Check your htaccess file. And look for hacked files: plugins/themes/etc; and update everything (including your PHP version). Change credentials everywhere (not just WP) using strong passwords.

Make sure your site is clean - there are many ways to insert code into a WP site (even the wp-config.php file may not be 'clean').

I use my own procedure to clean client sites: https://www.securitydawg.com/recovering-from-a-hacked-wordpress-site/ . There are many googles/bings/ducks on how to de-hack sites.